# Why does Intel Graphics Installer depend on ttf-ancient-fonts?

Tags: intel-graphics

I just tried installing `Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.5 for Linux*` from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads and it  installed `ttf-ancient-fonts`. Any ideas on why do they need it?

Related forum topic is https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/331 but I don't want to register there yet.

Comment: I don't see any reference to ancient fonts in the 01.org thread. The dependency seems silly based on the description of [ttf-ancient-fonts](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+package/ttf-ancient-fonts) but perhaps the Intel graphics installer wants to make sure the symbol blocks from the Unicode standard are covered. No idea really.

Comment: There is a newer version here: https://download.01.org/gfx/src/  and I dont see any direct references to ttf in the src folder. but, a gtk library could have some underlying dependency. or some other library.. i just saw references to gtk...

Comment: @int_ua - is your installation adjusted to unicode-utf8 charsets ?!

Comment: @dschinn1001 I didn't understand nor the first question nor the second comment, please elaborate.

Comment: recovery partition given or dual-boot installation?...

Comment: Single, Ubuntu taking the whole HDD. The question is answered, check out the answer below.

Comment: This means you simply shredder the fonts which are made of glass?!

Comment: Are you drunk or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We (the team who wrote the installer) use a few symbols like ⏳ (HOURGLASS WITH FLOWING SAND) in the UI (in some activity messages the installer sends and so forth): installing ttf-ancient-fonts means there's guaranteed to be a font with enough unicode coverage that they show up.

Comment: Who is "we"? Why isn't is a core system requirement, and only the Intel drivers?

Comment: We there is Intel, he didn't specify but that is Vivi Rodrigo the package maintainer who I emailed to get an answer for this question. He works for intel.

Comment: I'm not Rodrigo, but he did ask me to reply to this since I was on the installer team.

Comment: @fledermaus Maybe you should have explained that in the answer, so we can have a better understanding of it.  :)