# Ubuntu fonts are corrupted on certain windows

Tags: fonts, lightdm

I'm running ubuntu 14.10 on a lenovo yoga pro 3. Specifically I followed the instructions detailed here during the istallation process:

[Yoga 3 Linux HOWTO](https://github.com/longsleep/yoga3pro-linux/blob/master/Yoga%203%20Linux%20HOWTO.md)

When I login to Ubuntu sometimes the fonts are fine, other times they look as they do in this screen shot. (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post direct images). On certain applications however, ie chrome the fonts are fine.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Bo1.jpg)

As you can see some of the fonts in some of the windows are corrupted. This problem happened very rarely until recently when I did,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I've also tried things like restarting lightdm but to no eval.

Comment: No fix but some suggestions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command doesn't update your applications. It only updates the list of packages ("list of applications"). Use this to update your applications:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

To hopefully solve your actual problem, go to System Settings → Universal Access and make sure "Large Text" is off (should be default).

Then run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

When it's finished, open unity tweak tool and click "fonts". Choose smaller text sizes.