# Characteres not appear after sudo apt -get update

Tags: 14.04, unity, updates

I was installing an application and ended up giving sudo apt-get update, I restarted the computer and now Ubuntu is "disappearing" with some letters. Can anyone help me fix this?

[image]

[image]

******I try reinstall unity but this keep happens

Comment: Check out this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters

Comment: It sounds like video driver problem, let us know your hardware video model and make.

Comment: I execute this and works for me:
1. sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update, 2. dpkg --configure -a, 3.      sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: Is your problem solved?