# missing letter in between words on every application and system

Tags: 14.04, system

I just installed Ubuntu Studio 14.04.4 64 bits and a lot of my applications either the name of it or the function name went missing, example: Trash, it only shows h, when I selected it a few times then the correct name (Trash) then will appear, but after I use other application and go back to my desktop and same thing happened.

This is not just the applications but the browser and the system also have the same issue, right now when I am writing this question, my right side of the browser, Ubuntu similar questions list, I can't read the questions because some of the words were missing, I had to move my cursor to the question then the whole question will be readable to me.

Even my own question which is this one I have written, has the same issue. Hope I explain clearly, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have problems with the graphics card. Try 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'. A new kernel version will probably solve the issue. Check this [How do I fix fonts not rendering and missing letters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters) for more.

Hope it helps, thanks

Comment: Nope, I have similar issue with most letters on the dialogs not showing most of the time and I have  4.4.0-66-generic #87~14.04.1-Ubuntu. If there is a solution it would be going back to where this was working.

Comment: Quite the contrary, according to many reports there is a problem with Linux 4.4 and going back to 4.2 fixes it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1575000