# How to fix missing characters from font after awakening from suspend?

Tags: gnome, graphics, suspend, fonts, gui

I find that often after awakening from suspend on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 (I have only found this issue on the latest version, though I have not tried with GNOME 3.18 on 16.04) that I get this strange font issue which can't be fixed by restarting `gnome-shell` and seemingly only by restarting my entire machine:

[image: gnome-system-monitor font issue]

[image: Shutter font issue]

[image: File Chooser font issue]

[image: Title Bar font issue]

[image: gnome-control-center font issue]

I do not believe that this is a theme issue as I have tried all the built-in themes (including the dark and light versions) and it is the same for them all. Though it does not seem to affect `gnome-shell` areas, that is the top-bar, the Activities Overview, etc, are not affected for some reason. So what could this issue be caused by and how can I fix or workaround it?

**Information Update:**

I have had a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/633435/364819) but the only options in the `gnome-tweak-tool` for `Antialiasing` are `Rgba`, `None`, and `Grayscale`, but none of them seem to have any affect on the issue. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue with the Intel drivers. Perhaps you'll find an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters

Comment: @groovy354: I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried that one? http://askubuntu.com/a/640839

Comment: Not a solution, but maybe you can just log out to fix it instead of restarting? I have seemingly same issue on Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Log out does not help, actually this happens to me after switching user and back. Gnome flashback, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix fonts not rendering and missing letters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters)

Comment: @Lambart: Although they are similar issues, this is caused by a bug, it doesn't look like the other one is so given that the cause and solution are different I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I suspect you're right... although that ticket doesn't mention a connection to "suspend" (which was a key symptom of my issue--and this one here), the fix using `unity-tweaks` did the trick for me on a Mac Mini.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be symptom of a kernel bug since 4.4.6, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1573959) which reportedly got fixed in Linux kernel 4.8.x, and the fix will be in Ubuntu 17.04 (which will likely have 4.10 kernel).

On Fedora bug tracker, someone [reported](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1323762) that changing / adding this in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` helps:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "blt"
   Option      "TearFree"     "true"
EndSection
```

Didn't try, I am going to wait for 17.04.

To me, this happens also after switching to another user account and back.

Comment: In 16.04 the Xorg config files are placed in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. Shouldn't this file be placed there too?

Comment: What does the LTS mean, if this fix wont come to 16.04? Such a major issue, and no fix yet to 16.04? Switching to 17.04 is the only solution. Shame on canonical!

Comment: @ashishsony The fix is available for 16.04. Just update to a 4.8.x kernel, which is available in official 16.04 repositories.

Comment: +1, except that I think the issue started being shipped from kernel `4.4.0` as many people reported in the referenced ticket, instead of 4.4.6. I'm having this issue with 4.4.0-96, on my `14.04` machine.

Comment: Then possibly there are more bugs with these symptomps? Thanks for the info, rewording.

Comment: Didn't encounter the problem any more since modifying `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` (Ubuntu 16.04). Thanks!

Comment: I have this problem on 14.04 with kernel `Linux mars-hub 4.4.0-83-generic #106~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:10:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 4):

When my Ubuntu has display problems when recovering from suspend, I fix it with a quick visit to console: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Wait a couple of seconds if your display blinks, changes resolution etc. Then back: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: It won't fix for me

Comment: This will : http://askubuntu.com/questions/818390/unreadable-nautilus-and-thunderbird-in-gnome-session-please-see-screenshot

Comment: hm, after when I did that I can't return back

Answer (score 1):

Workaround, use kernel 4.8:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1573959

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and discovered that for some reason my laptop was using an old kernel version (4.4, rather than 4.15, currently) .I'm on 18.04, having upgraded from 16.04.

I installed the latest kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

That has fixed the issue.