# All fonts become invisible on occasion after unlock

Tags: 16.04, fonts, mate

Now and then, I'll unlock my computer and see this:

[image: fonts invisible]

You can see in the bottom-right corner that when I open the calendar, nothing is shown. This is true for most applications.

Now look at the bottom-left:

[image: fonts actually barely visible]

The fonts used in the MATE toolbar are, unlike most applications, just *mostly* invisible! They have changed color from white to a dark, translucent color that blends in with the rest of the panel.

What could possibly be causing this? A reboot fixes it, but I'd like to ensure that it doesn't happen again.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I have upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.
Before  you ask, I do not have a graphics card. I have integrated graphics:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: @Zanna Thank you for saving me from that embarrassment. ;)

Comment: The same problem on a fresh Ubuntu16.04/64b install. 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: maybbe this one helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/795278/how-to-fix-missing-characters-from-font-after-awakening-from-suspend