# Strange characters displayed after awakening from regular sleep Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, graphics, suspend, display

After awakening from a regular sleep in Ubuntu 18.04, I often notice strange characters bugs in the Gnome interface. I link screenshots to this post. The only way I found to fix it is to perform a reboot.

It happens to me with French and English interfaces, and it happened with 2 different Ubuntu 18.04 installations on my computer.

I though this issues may be related to [How to fix missing characters from font after awakening from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795278/how-to-fix-missing-characters-from-font-after-awakening-from-suspend), still none of the proposed solutions worked for me, and my characters didn't disappeared, but changed.

I guess it may be related to interference between my NVidia card (840M), the Intel Display HD card, and Gnome...

I am using NVidia additional drivers : GM108M (Geforce 840M) nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary, tested), on an Asus computer - UX303ln.

Thank you for reading!

[Desktop characters bug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvxuE.png)
[Application launcher characters bug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1iyC.png)

---

EDIT

I faced a new issue : after going to sleep mode, my computer wasn't able to recover from the dark screen.

I even tried ALT+SYST+[R, E, I, S, U, B] to reboot the computer, without success. I had to hard reboot by holding the power switch. One week ago, a similar problem caused my SSD to be corrupted. I had to buy a new one and that why I could say I tried two different Ubuntu installation... Maybe this is linked to the Data corruption issue with the new Linux version? https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.19.8-Released

By looking more specifically for this dark screen problem here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774950 , I discovered the "nouveau" driver issue concerning nVidia graphics cards. Two possibilities are proposed : downgrade the Linux Kernel to 4.14 or disable nouveau through GRUB. I have chosen the second option for now.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774950/comments/24

Set

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in the /etc/default/grub file, after that run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

I will answer this issue in a few days if I found out the problem not to occur anymore.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the EDIT above in the original question was the right guess.
My computer is able to recover from sleep. I sometimes still have those strange characters, but it happened to me only once in 3 weeks.

Also, a problem that may be related appeared in Windows : when I shutdown the computer, the power switch stays light on. REISUB doesn't affect the state, I have to hold the power switch and the switch light finally turns off. The problem may be on the bios layer... Computer Science...

Cheers!