# Ubuntu not rendering fonts completely after a wake from suspend

Tags: 16.04, xorg, i3-wm

This happens on Ubuntu 16.04 with `i3wm`, the processor is a Haswell (i54210u) with a HD 4400, using Intel drivers.

None of the tweak tools work with i3wm, how do I solve this issue.

Related to this, [How do I fix fonts not rendering and missing letters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters). Except with different hardware.

I have a dedicated GPU, but it's switched off via the nvidia-settings app.

`lshw -c video` gives me

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 0b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom                                                                                                                                                                                 
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   resources: irq:46 memory:c3000000-c33fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) `                                                                                                                                                   


 *-display                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       description: 3D controller                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]                                                                                                                                                                      
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       physical id: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       version: a1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       width: 64 bits                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       clock: 33MHz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       resources: irq:16 memory:c2000000-c2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

Comment: *nouveau* is for Nvidia but yours is Intel, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, I have an dedicated card too on my laptop, problem occurs with the Intel drivers, let me update the question.

Comment: Use intel drivers installer

Comment: https://01.org/linuxgraphics

Comment: You might want to check out this thread: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286337/unable-to-change-i3wm-scaling. Just a suggestion, as some users reported that changing scaling fixes the issue.

Comment: @HackToHell, Does it happen when you switch to TTY1 using (ctrl+alt+f1), login then run `sudo pm-suspend ` ?

Comment: @user.dz Haven't tried that

Comment: @Brask already in the latest version.