# Font rendering of GUI app

Tags: fonts

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Inetl i3. Intel Skylake integrated graphics.

I have an application running on a remote host (Oracle database installer).  I connect to that remote host from my Ubuntu laptop using putty with x-11 forwarding.  (have also used the native ssh with the -X switch).  In that putty (or ssh) session I launch the app.  The interface comes up, so there is no issue with networking and x11 redirection.  However, the app window is missing a lot of text, but not all.  The screen looks like this:  [image of interface on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GULK.png)  By contrast, peforming the very same operation (putty session to the very same remote server) from a Windows 7 machine gets the fully functional screen: [image of interface on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42BXY.png)

This appears to be very similar to [How do I fix fonts . . .](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters)  but in my case, it only exhibits on this one app, not the Ubuntu applets shown.  And when I tried to follow the advice there regarding installing 'ubuntu-tweaks', I got "Unable to locate package ubuntu-tweak".

Comment: Have you tried installing the true type fonts?  `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: Terrance - Ok, I tried that but when the ULA presents itself,  the text scrolls, but the window is unresponsive to either a mouse click on the <ok>, or to a press of the 'enter' key.

Comment: It should just be highlighted on the OK, as this is a text based screen.  You should only have to press 'enter' to accept.

Comment: @Terrance - that's what I would have thought.  But it is not highlighted and does not respond to the enter key.  (and I don't seem to be able to insert a screenshot here)

Comment: @Terrance - and just to put icing on the cake, at that point the only way out is to kill my ssh session in which I was running apt-get.  That then leaves the apt-get process in the background, where I have to use a 'ps ' command to locate it and a 'kill' command to terminate it.

Comment: Adding an answer you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [this](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb) one instead.  Once downloaded, go to the download location and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

*Link below as well.*

http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb

Hope this helps!

Comment: Was able to install the fonts but did not resolve the core issue.

Comment: @Edstevens Are you installing the Oracle Database for Linux?

Comment: yes, installing Oracle database for linux.  Something I've done literally hundreds of times over the years.  (my primary job for the last 20-some years has been Oracle DBA) The only thing different is I am running from a linux (Ubuntu) desktop instead of a Windows desktop.

Comment: @Edstevens Hmmm, I guess I don't have the ability to download Oracle 12 Database.  I have an account with them as I work on their servers, but I never agreed to their OTN I guess.  I was going to try to see if I could duplicate your issue.  Usually missing words like that can be subject to missing fonts.  I don't know what else could be missing from it.

Comment: Yes, you'll need an OTN account, but it's free.  When you say you have an account with them, what kind of account are you talking about?  What do you on their servers? What servers?