# Dolphin not working in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: filemanager, 18.10, dolphin

Dolphin is not working and showing any files. Its a fresh install. I tried installing through both the software store and terminal but unfortunately the result is same.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you get the same result booted from live media? Please [edit] the output of `dolphin -v` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Hey there, we need more info before we can help you out. Please edit with logs of dolphin -v's output into the post. Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed any other apps having the same problem (text not showing)?

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I fix fonts not rendering and missing letters?](https://askubuntu.com/q/584922/301745)